# Meu smartphone Samsung Galaxie S5 reinicia quando estou no meio de uma ligação

Tags: configuração, smartdevice

Já há mais de um mês que meu smartphone Galaxie S5 desliga automáticamente quando estou em meio a uma ligação e reinicia.  Isso acontece umas três vezes ao dia e imagino tratar-se de uma configuração errada.  Já procurei mas nada encontrei de errado.  Contudo, meu conhecimento de informática também não é grande coisa.  Estou evitando levar à assistência técnica porque dependo dele para o meu trabalho.  Alguma possibilidade de que possa tratar-se de um problema de configuração ?  Ou um defeito?  Ou o mais provável é que seja um vírus ?  Agradeço qualquer colaboração.

Comment: Esta pergunta está fora do escopo do site. Sugiro que olhe nos foruns do androidcentral ou xda-developers.

Comment: Desculpem-me.  É a primeira vez aqui.  Agradeço de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há nenhum tipo de configuração (certa ou errada) que possa fazer com que seu smartphone reinicie sozinho, principalmente sem lhe perguntar antes.

Segue abaixo algumas das prováveis razões:

1. Vírus: Se seu smartphone estiver infectado isto poderia ser uma causa. Neste caso baixe aplicativos anti-vírus como Avast por exemplo e faça uma varedura completa.
2. Erros de sistema: Por algum motivo seu android está corrompido e ao executar determinado comando gera um erro fatal que ocasiona a reinicialização. Neste caso a solução seria restaurar a instalação de fábrica, de preferência utilizando o Kies.
3. Problema de hardware: Falhas ou superaquecimento em componentes eletrônicos também podem ocasionar a reinicialização espontânea do aparelho. Em computadores por exemplo, se o processador superaquecer o sistema é reiniciado imediatamente, e dependendo do nível de aquecimento, o processador fica permanentemente danificado e passa a reinicializar sempre que atinge determinada temperatura, mesmo que o problema de refrigeração tenha sido sanado. Neste caso a solução é levar para a assistência técnica autorizada para fazer um diagnóstico do seu aparelho.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Daniel.  Seguirei os passos que vc propôs.